# No battery temperature updates on HTC Hero / Android 2.1

Tags: android, htc-hero

I'm writing an Android app using old Android phones dedicated to temperature monitoring. Now I'm having problem with an HTC Hero running Android 2.1 update-1. **It doesn't receive updates of the battery temperature sensor**. It only gets an initial value. It does however receive updates of external power plugged in status. If the external power source is changed **a new temperature is received**.

**Is this behaviour set by the hardware or is it anything I can do about it?**

I'm using a BroadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);

BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive, action = " + intent.getAction());

        float temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 999) / 10f;
        boolean externalPower = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0) != 0);

        // ...
    }

};
```

This works fine on a Galaxy S4 / Android 4.3.

Like I said, if the external power source is changed (charger is plugged in or unplugged) the receiver is always called, and a new temperature is received.

Re-regestering the receiver doesn't help.

I've tried manually getting the Intent like this in intervals, but the temperature is constant (even if it definitely changed).

```
handleBatteryIntent(registerReceiver(null, filter));
```

Seems the temperature is only updated when the external power source status (EXTRA_PLUGGED) has changed.

I've tried two other battery apps, and they have the same problem.

Comment: Looks its hardware specific feature. Are you sure that your HTC Hero has the required sensor?

Comment: Well I do get correct temperature values when external power changes. However I've done more testing and `SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);` returns null. So I'm not sure.